# Properties of renamed name ranges via VBA

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I try to document some large spreadsheets, using VBA, I have named ranges for Data retireval from Access, but the name is changed from the standard Data_Query_From etc. into a recognisable name. In the Name manager these names show, but using in VBA the properties of the Workbook Names, I only see the original names. How can I retrieve the properties with the given name, or the connection between given name and the technical name?

Comment: Are you talking about the tab names (aka worksheet names) in VBA?

Comment: No, I mean ranges in sheets, that you can use in formulas, to refer to a set of cells, but then the ones that get automatically a name, like data tables and external input from Access. These are often renamed to a more understandable name. I look for that connection, retrievable via VBA